# Does Channel9 have API?

Tags: api, video

Simple and short. I was wondering does popular [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) have some application interface so that we can programatically browse their videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/445028-Does-Channel-9-offer-an-API-for-its-video-content) mentions that web services exist that will list their content, but does not provide any URLs.

Duncan Mackenzie Nov 23, 2008 at 11:16 PM:

> we have a bunch of web services that
>   can return lists of videos by tag...
>   but you could do that via RSS as well
>   ... what did you have in mind (what
>   specific requests would you want to
>   make?)

Comment: did u get the web service to access the videos? I am also trying to develop an app for channel 9